# Import csv file into table in pgAdmin using COPY command

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-copy

I'm trying to  import csv file's table into pgAdmin using COPY command and getting the error:

> ERROR: could not open file "R:\myfile.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
> HINT: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to  read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

The statement is:

```
copy tst_copy from 'R:\myfile.csv'
```

Comment: I don't think pgAdmin has a /copy capability like psql has. Did you notice the error message: You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.

Comment: However, did you check https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.2/import_export_data.html

Comment: i new about import/export dialog option but i need to do it with command ( for future job)  if it possible

Comment: Not with the COPY-statement because that's a server side statement and not a client side statement. You could use a client side protocol that supports copy, that is what psql does.